# Bad Request on JSON Call to Sharepoint List

Tags: json, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I am attemtping to create a sharepoint list workflow using sharepoint designer that (for now) will simply return the count of items in the list. I will later use this count to execute a loop thru all the items in the list, but for now, just trying to get the count.

I have tried a variety of approaches, but essentially I have 
- initialized the workflow and at start, capture the URL of the site by setting a variable to the Workflow Context:Current Site URL

- Using Build I have created dictionary items for Accept and Content-type and Output to Variable:  JSonRequestHeader
- I then execute the Call using the previously captured URL variable, concatenating to it ../api/web/lists/GetByTitle('my list name')/items?$select=mykeyfield
- I am logging capture information in variables and the URL to workflow history (and it looks perfect).

However, after all of above, I am getting a Bad Response from the workflow log entry in which I am capturing the response.  Even in simply manually inserting the constructed URL into a browser, I also get a bad response

Image of result when I paste constructed link into browser:

[image]

I know the website url is good, but something must be wrong with rest of string I am concatenating.  I have looked a numerous videos and "how to's" on web and sure seems like I am doing it correctly.  I am just wondering if it is possible that our MS managed Sharepoints restrict such calls, or there is some setting I have to turn on, to make it work?

Any thoughts, appreciated.

Sharepoint designer code:  Maybe not so helpful, but here it is nonetheless[image]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you shared seems not valid English character.

[image]

Comment: Thx for response.  The structure of the URL (if that is what you are saying) is correct, unless you are seeing something that is wrong.  Later, what I did, was add a filter statement to include one of the columns on the very end, and then, it worked fine (ie, exact same url, except I asked for the "Top" number of rows. In other words, I know I have 1200 items in the list, so I added "?$top=2000" (without the quotes) to the end of the URL, and it worked fine.  So not sure why the original URL is failing.